# Asset pipeline minify adds question mark to CSS header

Tags: css, gradle, asset-pipeline, minify

I am running a Grails project where Gradle uses the assets pipeline plugin (2.9.1) with the following configuration in the Gradle build file:

```
assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = false
    enableGzip = false
    //excludes = ['**/w3.css']
}
```

I am using the w3.css stylesheet which starts like this:

```
/* W3.CSS 1.96 by J.E.Refsnes. Do not remove this line. */
*{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-    sizing:border-box}
/* Extract from normalize.css by Nicolas Gallagher and Jonathan Neal     git.io/normalize */
html{-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}
...etcetera...
```

But when I build my project and the assets are put together I end up with an extra question mark in the beginning of the w3.css:

```
?/* W3.CSS 1.96 by J.E.Refsnes. Do not remove this line. */
*{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-    sizing:border-box}
/* Extract from normalize.css by Nicolas Gallagher and Jonathan Neal     git.io/normalize */
html{-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}
```

How do I get rid of this question mark being added? And how does this happen? I already upgraded the assets plugin from 2.5.0 to 2.9.1. But that didn't solve the problem. Is there something I am overseeing? This question mark actually gives an issue by that the first asterisk in front of the webkit border box element isn't being picked up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The question mark probably means that there is a problem with the file encodings and how they are handled. You can manually [set the locale](http://www.asset-pipeline.com/manual/index.html#encoding) for your Asset Pipeline file. For CSS, it would look something like this:

```
/**
 *= require file1.css
 *= require file2.css
 *= encoding UTF-8
 */
```

Or for Javascript, try:

```
//= require file1.js
//= require file2.js
//= encoding UTF-8
```